# Android ZBar custom integration

Tags: android, zbar

Good day. I'm trying to create tabbed application (via TabHost), tab bar with icons should be available at all time. However one of my activities implements [ZBar component](https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner). The recommend way of usage is via intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ZBarScannerActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST);
```

But in this case camera preview just fills the whole available surface. How do I run this component in some frame? I suppose I can try to do that via WebView, but I can't figure out how to get scanning result in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WebView? No, that's a bad idea.

You can just call `tabHost.setContent(intent);` and add the intent.

`startActivityForResult()` just opens a new `Activity` window so don't even use that.

Example:

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("HOME")
.setContent(new Intent(this,ZBarScannerActivity.class)));
```

Comment: Thanks this helps, however I can't recieve scanning result this way. Application just quits on code recognition.

Comment: How are you trying to receive the scanning results? What error are you getting?

Comment: Aww nevermind, I took another way - not ZBarScannerActivity but base camera control class. So I can call my own activity from TabHost with methods of that class. Thanks for help!